# 'Detection updating interface' in Unity3D Engine for Huawei AppGallery

Tags: unity-game-engine, huawei-mobile-services, appgallery, self-updating

How can I implement 'update interface' when a new app version is released based on Unity3D?

I have received this message from AppGallery review team : "We found that the detection updating interface isn't called in HMS after the app's startup".

The only documents that I have found is for implementing in Android studio in this link : [Updating an App](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/appgallerykit-app-update-0000001055118286)

Answer (score 0):

After an app is launched or when a user proactively checks whether there is a later version, call the related API of the HMS Core SDK to check whether there is a later version available on AppGallery. If so, display a pop-up asking the user whether to update the app.

[image]

The key steps for achieving this function are as follows:

1. A user triggers an update check, for example, by launching the app or manually performing the check on the update check page.
2. The app calls `JosApps.getAppUpdateClient` to request to initialize the `AppUpdateClient` instance.

   `AppUpdateClient client = JosApps.getAppUpdateClient(this);`
3. The HMS Core SDK returns the `AppUpdateClient` instance of the current app to the app.
4. The app calls the `AppUpdateClient.checkAppUpdate` method to request an update check.

```
public void checkUpdate() {
    AppUpdateClient client = JosApps.getAppUpdateClient(this);
    client.checkAppUpdate(this, new UpdateCallBack(this));
}
```

5. The HMS Core SDK queries the latest app version information on AppGallery.
6. AppGallery sends the app version information back to the HMS Core SDK.
7. The HMS Core SDK sends the check result to the app through a callback.
8. The app checks the `ApkUpgradeInfo` instance returned by the `onUpdateInfo` method in the callback result and checks whether an update is available.

```
private static class UpdateCallBack implements CheckUpdateCallBack {
    private WeakReference<MainActivity> weakMainActivity;
    private UpdateCallBack(MainActivity apiActivity) {
        this.weakMainActivity = new WeakReference<MainActivity>(apiActivity);
    }
    public void onUpdateInfo(Intent intent) {
        if (intent != null) {
            MainActivity apiActivity = null;
            if (weakMainActivity != null && weakMainActivity.get() != null){
                apiActivity = weakMainActivity.get();
            }
            // Obtain the update status code. Default_value indicates the default return code when status cannot be obtained, which is determined by the app.
            int status = intent.getIntExtra(UpdateKey.STATUS, DEFAULT_VALUE);
            // Error code. You are advised to record it.
            int rtnCode = intent.getIntExtra(UpdateKey.FAIL_CODE, DEFAULT_VALUE);
             // Failure information. You are advised to record it.
            String rtnMessage = intent.getStringExtra(UpdateKey.FAIL_REASON);
            Serializable info = intent.getSerializableExtra(UpdateKey.INFO);
            // Check whether the app has an update by checking whether info obtained is of the ApkUpgradeInfo type.
            if (info instanceof ApkUpgradeInfo) {
                // Call the showUpdateDialog API to display the update pop-up. The demo has an independent button for displaying the pop-up. Therefore, this API is not called here. For details, please refer to the checkUpdatePop() method.
                if (apiActivity != null) {
                    apiActivity.showLog("There is a new update");
                    apiActivity.apkUpgradeInfo = (ApkUpgradeInfo) info;
                }
            }
            if(apiActivity != null) {
                apiActivity.showLog("onUpdateInfo status: " + status + ", rtnCode: " + rtnCode + ", rtnMessage: " + rtnMessage);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

9. The app calls the `AppUpdateClient.showUpdateDialog` method to request to display the update pop-up for the user.

```
public void checkUpdatePop(boolean forceUpdate) {
    AppUpdateClient client = JosApps.getAppUpdateClient(this);
    client.showUpdateDialog(this, apkUpgradeInfo, forceUpdate);
    Log.i(TAG, "checkUpdatePop success");
}
```

10. The HMS Core SDK displays the update pop-up for the user.
11. The user chooses to update the app on the update confirmation page.
12. The HMS Core SDK sends a request to AppGallery to download the latest app installation package.
13. AppGallery returns the app package to the HMS Core SDK. The HMS Core SDK starts to install the app after the download is complete.

For more details, pls kindly check [this docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/AppGallery-connect-Guides/appgallerykit-game-update-0000001055756860?ha_source=hms1).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have implemented IAP by "EvilMindDevs/hms-unity-plugin". I think the document that you have mentioned is for android studio. Is there an explicit way for implementation in Unity3D? @shirley

Comment: hi@Abolfazl Nazeran, May I ask whether your app will be released to Chinese Mainland?

Comment: hi @shirley, yes my main goal is to publish the app to Chinese Mainland and as you know without implementing 'update feature' it is not possible to publish an app to Chinese Mainland.

Comment: hi@Abolfazl Nazeran, Thanks for your feedback. According to the team, this interface will release in next week's friday. You can download it from gitHub at that time.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time to investigate regard to this feature. It will be great. @shirley